# How can I enhance my linkedlist implementation in java?

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list

I recently implemented Linked List on my own. I did not use generics as I am still learning. How can I improve it:

```
package datastructures;

class LinkedList
{
    Node head = null; 
    Node tail = null;
    int size = 0;

    public void add(int data)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.setElement(data);
        if(head == null){head = n; tail = n;}
        else
        {
            tail.setNext(n);
            tail = n;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void size()
    {
        System.out.println("Size of the list is " + size);
    }

    public void addFront(int data)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.setElement(data);

        if(head == null)    {   head = n; tail = n;   }
        else
        {
            n.setNext(head);
            head = n;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void addLast(int data)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.setElement(data);

        if(head == null){head = n; tail = n;}
        else
        {
            tail.setNext(n);
            tail = n;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void removeFirst()
    {
        if(size==0){return ;}
        else
        {
            Node n = head.getNext();
            head = n;
        }
        size--;
    }

    public void removeLast()
    {
        if(size==0){return ;}
        else
        {
            Node tmp , prev = null;
            tmp = head;

        while(tmp != null)
        {
            if(tmp.getNext() == tail){prev = tmp;}
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
            tail = prev;
            tail.setNext(null);
        }
        size--;
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        Node cNode = head;
        while(cNode != null)
        {
            System.out.println(cNode.getElement()+" ");
            cNode = cNode.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(6);
        l.add(7);
        l.add(8);
        l.addLast(9);
        l.addFront(0);
        l.printList();

        System.out.println("Head Node is "+l.head.getElement());
        System.out.println("Tail Node is "+l.tail.getElement());
        l.size();

        System.out.println("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\Before removing the first element////////");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\After removing the first element and removing the last element////////");
        System.out.println("");

        l.removeFirst();
        l.removeLast();
        l.printList();
        System.out.println("Head Node is "+l.head.getElement());
        System.out.println("Tail Node is "+l.tail.getElement());
        l.size();
    }

}
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public void setElement(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getElement()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
            return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        this.next = n;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 Coding conventions**

In Java, you should keep the opening curly brace on the same row as the token it relates to. Instead of writing

```
public void add(int data)
{
    ...
}

...
else 
{
    ...
}
```

you should write

```
public void add(int data) {
    ...
}

...
else {
    ...
}
```

What comes to other conventions, you should have **a single space** between **`if`**-keyword and the opening parenthesis of the condition. Instead of

```
if(foo(bar)) ...
```

you should write

```
if (foo(bar)) ...
```

Also, what comes to the **`if`** keyword, you should have **another single space** between the closing parenthesis of the condition and the opening curly brace. So, instead of

```
if (foo(bar)){
    ...
}
```

you should write

```
if (foo(bar)) {
    ...
}
```

Now, I suggest you do not write more than one statement on a single line. Instead of

```
{head = n; tail = n;}
```

it would be nicer to write

```
... {
    head = n;
    tail = n;
}
```

**2 Field initializers**

The following is superfluous:

```
Node head = null; 
Node tail = null;
int size = 0;
```

By default, Java initializes the object fields to **`null`** and integer fields to 0. Also, they **must** be declared **`private`**, since otherwise whatever is in your package, it may tamper with the fields. So, you should write

```
private Node head;
private Node tail;
private int size;
```

**3 `class Node`**

I think it would be a better idea to declare **`Node`** as a private static inner class of **`LinkedList`** (see **Summa summarum** for details). Also, I would rename **`data`** to **`datum`** since it is the singular form of the word. Also, **`datum/data`** may be declared **`final`** since it is not modified. Moreover, you could declare both **`data`** and **`next`** as private and provide appropriate getters and setters.

**4 `printList`**

The conventional way to do what you do in **`printList`** is to override the **`Object.toString`** method returning a string representing the contents of your list.

**5 `remove*`**

Your list would be more useful, if your **`remove*`** methods returned the datum removed from the list.

**6 `size()`**

Printing the current size of the list to standard output is not a good idea. Instead, just return the size and let the caller do whatever (s)he wants with it (for example, print it to console).

**Summa summarum**

Putting all pieces together, I had this implementation in mind:

```
package datastructures;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;

    private static final class Node {

        private final int datum;
        private Node next;

        Node(final int datum) {
            this.datum = datum;
        }

        int getDatum() {
            return datum;
        }

        Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        void setNext(Node n) {
            this.next = n;
        }

    }

    public void add(final int datum) {
        Node node = new Node(datum);

        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(node);
        }

        tail = node;
        size++;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void addFirst(int datum) {
        Node node = new Node(datum);

        if (head == null) {
            tail = node;
        } else {
            node.setNext(head);
        }

        head = node;
        size++;
    }

    public void addLast(int datum) {
        add(datum);
    }

    public int removeFirst() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Removing from an empty list.");
        }

        final Node firstNode = head;
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
        return firstNode.getDatum();
    }

    public int removeLast() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Removing from an empty list.");
        }

        final Node lastNode = tail;
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;

        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        tail = previous;

        if (tail != null) {
            tail.setNext(null);
        }

        size--;
        return lastNode.getDatum();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return "[]";
        }

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        sb.append(head.getDatum());
        Node node = head.getNext();

        while (node != null) {
            sb.append(", ").append(node.getDatum());
            node = node.getNext();
        }

        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(6);
        l.add(7);
        l.add(8);
        l.addLast(9);
        l.addFirst(0);
        System.out.println(l);

        System.out.println("Head Node is " + l.head.getDatum());
        System.out.println("Tail Node is " + l.tail.getDatum());
        l.size();

        System.out.println("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\Before removing the first element////////");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\After removing the first element and removing the last element////////");
        System.out.println("");

        l.removeFirst();
        l.removeLast();
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println("Head Node is " + l.head.getDatum());
        System.out.println("Tail Node is " + l.tail.getDatum());
        l.size();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't addLast pretty useless now? :)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html : It's just an alias. Sometimes it makes sense to be more explicit what computation one invokes.

Comment: Yes I agree, but having two methods which do exactly the same thing seems a bit superfluous to me. Bit of an opinionated thing I guess, but I would keep just one of them.

Comment: But it can save you typing 4 characters, which is nice. :P